# How to convert InnerText to InnerHtml in Webbrowser Control in C#?

Tags: c#, controls, browser, wysiwyg, spell-checking

I'm working on a WYSIWYG editor with builtin spell checker [Hunspell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell) and online highlighting of misspelled words. I'm using Webbrowser control as a html handler. It's a way easy to spell check text than html in webbrowser control, but following this way I'm losing all html formatting.
So the question is: is there any way to spell check body innertext and then convert it to body innerhtml with previous formatting? (with no use of [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or [Majestic12](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/) or [SgmlReader](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader) or [ZetaHtmlTidy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ZetaHtmlTidy.aspx)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a code example and what your result is when using said control, losing formatting?

Comment: I'm using a sample code snippet from hunspell website. I can highlight misspelled words in innertext, but I can't do that in innerhtml without losing it's formatting. To be honest, parsing and spell checking innerhtml is a pain in a butt (picking words wrapped in tags, wrap misspelled words in another tags to highlight them, also one word can be delimetered with several tags). That's why I'm asking about the easy way to convert html to text.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to checking the spelling of the `innterText` property of a given element, a better approach might be to loop through the child elements, and check the spelling of each child's `innerText` instead.

This approach, while possibly limiting context-based spell-checking, should keep the markup intact.

**Note:** You might want to take into consideration that each child node may *also* contain further children.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to check the spelling of the innerText property, but when replacing any changed words, I replaced them within the innerHTML. This was rather easy when changing all instances of a misspelled word. Simply use a Regular Expression to gather the indices of all matching words in the innerHTML and replace each one.

```
Regex wordEx = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
MatchCollection mcol = wordEx.Matches(webEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml);

foreach (Match m in mcol)
{
  //Basic checking for whether this word is an HTML tag. This is not perfect.
  if (m.Value == e.Word && webEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Substring(m.Index -1, 1) != "<")
  {
    wordIndeces.Add(m.Index);
  }
}

foreach (int curWordTextIndex in wordIndeces)
{
   Word word = Word.GetWordFromPosition(webEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml, curWordTextIndex);
   string tmpText = webEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Remove(word.Start, word.Length);
   webEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml = tmpText.Insert(word.Start, e.NewWord);
}

UpdateSpellingForm(e.TextIndex);
```

When replacing a single instance, I just looped through the InnerText to find which instance needs to be replaced. Then I looped through the InnerHTML until I found the correct instance and replaced it.